# What is the memory allocation when you return a function in Golang?

Tags: function, go, compiler-construction

Here is a simplified code

```golang
func MyHandler(a int) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteCode(a)
    })
}
```

Whenever a http request comes MyHandler will be called, and it will return a function which will be used to handle the request. So whenever a http request comes a new function object will be created. Function is taken as the first class in Go. I'm trying to understand what actually happened when you return a function from memory's perspective. When you return a value, for example an integer, it will occupy 4 bytes in stack. So how about return a function and lots of things inside the function body? Is it an efficient way to do so? What's shortcomings?

Comment: "When you return a value, for example an integer, it will occupy 4 bytes in stack." This is basically wrong as integers might be 4 or 8 or some other size and Go the language even doesn't have the concept of a stack (only some _implementations_ use a stack).  " I'm trying to understand what actually happened when you return a function from memory's perspective." there is nothing much to understand as this is an implementation detail and the WASM and the z/OS implementation might do differently and even Go 1.17 might do differently than Go 1.16

Comment: If you ask "How does Go 1.16.5 implement functions closures on linux/arm64?" the question becomes answerable. See e.g. the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not used to closures, they may seem a bit magic.  They are, however, easy to implement in compilers:

- The compiler finds any variables that must be *captured* by the closure.  It puts them into a working area that will be allocated and remain allocated as long as the closure itself exists.
- The compiler then generates the inner function with a secret extra parameter, or some other runtime trickery,<sup>1</sup> such that *calling* the function activates the closure.

Because the returned function accesses its closure variables through the compile-time arrangement, there's nothing special needed.  And since Go is a garbage-collected language, there's nothing else needed either: the pointer to the closure keeps the closure data alive until the pointer is gone because the function cannot be called any more, at which point the closure data evaporates (well, at the next GC).

---

<sup>1</sup>GCC sometimes uses *trampolines* to do this for C, where trampolines are executable code generated at runtime.  The executable code may set a register or pass an extra parameter or some such.  This can be expensive since something treated as data at runtime (generated code) must be turned into executable code at runtime (possibly requiring a system call and potentially requiring that some supervisory code "vet" the resulting runtime code).

Go does not *need* any of this because the language was defined with closures in mind, so implementors don't, er, "close off" any easy ways to make this all work.  Some runtime ABIs are defined with closures in mind as well, e.g., register `r1` is reserved as the closure-variables pointer in all pointer-to-function types, or some such.

Answer (score 1):

Actual function size is irrelevant. When you return a function like this, memory will be allocated for the closure, that is, any variables in the scope that the function uses. In this case, a pointer will be returned containing the address of the function and a pointer to the closure, which will contain a reference to the variable `a`.